# How do you add an item to a Unionized SQL View?

Tags: sql, database, select, union, crystal-reports-xi

I am working to make an automated report in Crystal Reports which requires me to add in a table to an existing, pre-written view. The view contains a Union operation which is preventing me from using the view as normal. What I have done is manualy add-in the data (about halfway through).

The item required for the report is tblSOPartsUsed.Memo. which i have added into BOTH select queries. In the join between tblCustomerInventory and tblSOPartsUsed the .Memo table only appears in the PartsUsed table, not in the CustomerInventory.

1. First Select Query Location

   ```
                 tblCustomerInventory.SerialNumber AS ExchangeSerialNumber, **tblSOPartsUsed.Memo AS SOPartsNotes**, tblInvoiceDetail.Taxable AS DetailIsTaxable,
   ```
2. First From Query Location

   ```
                 tblCustomerInventory FULL OUTER JOIN
                 tblSOPartsUsed INNER JOIN
   ```

I have outlined the second Select and From in exactly the same way.

Can someone please shed some light, i've tried EVERYTHING!

The full code is below...

```
SELECT InvoiceAssemblyPriceBook.Features AS AssemblyFeatures,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.EachQuantity AS AssemblyEachQuantity,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.FKInvoiceDetail AS AssemblyFKInvoiceDetail,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.InvoiceAssemblyDetailKeyID,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.ItemID AS AssemblyItemID,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.ItemDescription AS AssemblyItemDescription,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.PrintOnInvoice AS AssemblyPrintOnInvoice,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.Quantity AS AssemblyQuantity,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.SellingPrice AS AssemblySellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.TotalSellingPrice AS AssemblyTotalSellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.Type AS AssemblyType,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.UnitOfMeasure AS AssemblyUnitOfMeasure,
    tblInvoiceDetail.AssemblyType AS DetailAssemblyType,
    tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceDetailKeyID,
    tblInvoiceDetail.ItemDescription AS DetailItemDescription,
    tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID AS DetailItemID,
    tblInvoiceDetail.PrintOnInvoice AS DetailPrintOnInvoice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.Quantity AS DetailQuantity,
    tblInvoiceDetail.SellingPrice AS DetailSellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.TotalSellingPrice AS DetailTotalSellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.Type AS DetailType,
    tblInvoices.AccountNumber,
    tblInvoices.Comments,
    tblInvoices.ContractNumber,
    tblInvoices.Deposit,
    tblInvoices.Freight,
    tblInvoices.GSTax,
    tblInvoices.InvoiceDate,
    tblInvoices.InvoiceNumber,
    tblInvoices.PaidDate,
    tblInvoices.QuoteNumber,
    tblInvoices.SalesTaxPercent,
    CASE 
        WHEN tblInvoiceDetail.SoNumber IS NULL
            THEN tblInvoices.SONumber
        ELSE tblInvoiceDetail.SoNumber
        END AS SONumber,
    tblInvoices.STATUS,
    tblInvoices.StatusDate,
    tblInvoices.Tax,
    tblInvoices.TotalAmountDue,
    tblInvoices.TotalComment,
    tblInvoices.TotalDollarsDiscounted,
    tblInvoices.TotalGrossSell,
    tblInvoices.TotalNetSell,
    tblInvoices.TradeIn,
    tblInvoices.WorkOrderNumber,
    tblPriceLevels.IsRepairLevel,
    tblServiceOrders.ContractNumber AS ServiceOrderContractNumber,
    tblSysCompanySettings.HideGSTaxRelatedInformation,
    tblSysCompanySettings.ItemsServicedPrintOnInvoice,
    tblSysDisclaimerSettings.SalesInvoiceDisclaimer,
    tblSysDisclaimerSettings.ServiceInvoiceDisclaimer,
    tblSysPBSettings.PrintItemorPartNum,
    VoidedByReps.RepName AS VoidedByRepName,
    tblInvoices.TotalNetInvoice,
    InvoiceDetailPriceBook.PartNumber AS DetailPartNumber,
    InvoiceDetailPriceBook.UnitOfMeasure AS DetailUnitOfMeasure,
    InvoiceDetailPriceBook.Features AS DetailFeatures,
    tblSysDisclaimerSettings.ContractInvoiceDisclaimer,
    tblInvoices.ProviderTax,
    tblServiceOrders.BriefDescription AS SOBriefDescription,
    tblInvoices.GSTaxComputedBeforeTradeIn,
    tblInvoices.TaxComputedBeforeTradeIn,
    tblInvoices.ProviderTaxRate,
    tblInvoices.FreightTaxable,
    tblInvoices.GSTIsTaxable,
    tblInvoices.ProjectKeyID,
    InvoicesReps.RepName,
    tblAccounts.AccountNumber AS Expr1,
    tblAccounts.AccountID,
    tblInvoices.Terms,
    tblInvoices.Reference,
    tblInvoices.ARCustomerNumber,
    tblInvoices.PONumber,
    tblInvoices.ShipVia,
    tblServiceOrders.DateRequested,
    tblServiceOrders.DateOpened,
    tblServiceOrders.SONumber AS ServiceOrderSONumber,
    tblSysReportSettings.InvoiceCommentsAtEnd,
    tblInvoices.SourceDocument,
    tblTaxCodes.HasTieredDistrict,
    tblExchange.ExchangeKeyID,
    tblCustomerInventory.ItemID AS ExchangeItemID,
    tblCustomerInventory.ItemDescription AS ExchangeItemDescription,
    tblCustomerInventory.SerialNumber AS ExchangeSerialNumber,
    tblSOPartsUsed.Memo AS SOPartsNotes,
    tblInvoiceDetail.Taxable AS DetailIsTaxable,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.Taxable AS AssemblyIsTaxable,
    tblInvoices.IsFinalProgressiveInvoice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.IsProgressiveInvoiceItem,
    tblInvoices.IsProgressiveInvoice,
    tblInvoices.TotalPriceCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalTaxCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalGSTaxCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalProviderTaxCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalFreightCredited,
    tblInvoices.DiscountAllowed,
    tblInvoices.AmountPaid,
    (
        SELECT MAX(SOItemsServicedKeyID) AS Expr1
        FROM tblSOItemsServiced
        WHERE (SONumber = tblServiceOrders.SONumber)
        ) AS SOItemsServicedKeyID,
    tblInvoiceDetail.CommentOnly,
    ServiceOrderContacts.ContactName AS SOContactName,
    tblServiceOrders.ContactPhone AS SOContactPhone,
    tblServiceOrders.ContactPhoneLocation AS SOContactPhoneLocation,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) FormattedPhoneNumber
        FROM tblPhoneNumbers
        WHERE (ContactNumber = 0)
            AND (PrimaryIndicator = 1)
            AND (COALESCE(PhoneLocation, '') <> 'Fax')
            AND (AccountNumber = tblAccounts.AccountNumber)
        ) AS AccountPhone,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) PhoneLocation
        FROM tblPhoneNumbers AS tblPhoneNumbers_1
        WHERE (ContactNumber = 0)
            AND (PrimaryIndicator = 1)
            AND (COALESCE(PhoneLocation, '') <> 'Fax')
            AND (AccountNumber = tblAccounts.AccountNumber)
        ) AS AccountPhoneLocation,
    COALESCE(tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount.AmountDue, 0.00) AS AmountDue,
    COALESCE(tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount.Unappliedpayments, 0.00) AS Unappliedpayments,
    tblTaxCodes.IsHarmonizedTaxCode,
    tblInvoices.GSTax + tblInvoices.Tax AS HSTax
FROM tblPriceBook AS InvoiceAssemblyPriceBook
RIGHT JOIN tblPriceBook AS InvoiceDetailPriceBook
RIGHT JOIN tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail
RIGHT JOIN tblCustomerInventory
FULL JOIN tblSOPartsUsed
INNER JOIN tblExchange
    ON tblSOPartsUsed.SOPartsUsedKeyID = tblExchange.FKSOPartsUsed
        ON tblCustomerInventory.CustomerInventoryKeyID = tblExchange.FKCustomerInventory RIGHT JOIN tblInvoiceDetail
        ON tblSOPartsUsed.FKInvoiceDetail = tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceDetailKeyID
            ON tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.FKInvoiceDetail = tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceDetailKeyID
                ON InvoiceDetailPriceBook.ItemID = tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID
                    ON InvoiceAssemblyPriceBook.ItemID = tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.ItemID LEFT JOIN tblPriceLevels
                    ON tblInvoiceDetail.PriceLevel = tblPriceLevels.PriceLevelsKeyID RIGHT JOIN tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount INNER JOIN tblAccounts
                ON tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount.AccountNumber = tblAccounts.AccountNumber RIGHT JOIN tblReps AS VoidedByReps RIGHT JOIN tblInvoices AS tblInvoices LEFT JOIN tblTaxCodes
        ON tblInvoices.SalesTaxCode = tblTaxCodes.SalesTaxCode LEFT JOIN tblReps AS InvoicesReps
        ON tblInvoices.SalesRep = InvoicesReps.RepNumber
            ON VoidedByReps.RepNumber = tblInvoices.StatusBy LEFT JOIN tblServiceOrders LEFT JOIN tblContacts AS ServiceOrderContacts
        ON tblServiceOrders.ContactNumber = ServiceOrderContacts.ContactNumber
            ON tblInvoices.SONumber = tblServiceOrders.SONumber
                ON tblAccounts.AccountNumber = tblInvoices.AccountNumber
                    ON tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceNumber = tblInvoices.InvoiceNumber LEFT JOIN tblContacts AS tblContacts
                    ON tblAccounts.PrimaryContactNumber = tblContacts.ContactNumber CROSS JOIN tblSysPBSettings CROSS JOIN tblSysCompanySettings CROSS JOIN tblSysReportSettings CROSS JOIN tblSysDisclaimerSettings
WHERE (tblInvoices.MSPAgreementNumber = 0)

UNION ALL

SELECT InvoiceAssemblyPriceBook.Features AS AssemblyFeatures,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.EachQuantity AS AssemblyEachQuantity,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.FKInvoiceDetail AS AssemblyFKInvoiceDetail,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.InvoiceAssemblyDetailKeyID,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.ItemID AS AssemblyItemID,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.ItemDescription AS AssemblyItemDescription,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.PrintOnInvoice AS AssemblyPrintOnInvoice,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.Quantity AS AssemblyQuantity,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.SellingPrice AS AssemblySellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.TotalSellingPrice AS AssemblyTotalSellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.Type AS AssemblyType,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.UnitOfMeasure AS AssemblyUnitOfMeasure,
    tblInvoiceDetail.AssemblyType AS DetailAssemblyType,
    tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceDetailKeyID,
    tblInvoiceDetail.ItemDescription AS DetailItemDescription,
    tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID AS DetailItemID,
    tblInvoiceDetail.PrintOnInvoice AS DetailPrintOnInvoice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.Quantity AS DetailQuantity,
    tblInvoiceDetail.SellingPrice AS DetailSellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.TotalSellingPrice AS DetailTotalSellingPrice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.Type AS DetailType,
    tblInvoices.AccountNumber,
    tblInvoices.Comments,
    tblInvoices.ContractNumber,
    tblInvoices.Deposit,
    tblInvoices.Freight,
    tblInvoices.GSTax,
    tblInvoices.InvoiceDate,
    tblInvoices.InvoiceNumber,
    tblInvoices.PaidDate,
    tblInvoices.QuoteNumber,
    tblInvoices.SalesTaxPercent,
    CASE 
        WHEN tblInvoiceDetail.SoNumber IS NULL
            THEN tblInvoices.SONumber
        ELSE tblInvoiceDetail.SoNumber
        END AS SONumber,
    tblInvoices.STATUS,
    tblInvoices.StatusDate,
    tblInvoices.Tax,
    tblInvoices.TotalAmountDue,
    tblInvoices.TotalComment,
    tblInvoices.TotalDollarsDiscounted,
    tblInvoices.TotalGrossSell,
    tblInvoices.TotalNetSell,
    tblInvoices.TradeIn,
    tblInvoices.WorkOrderNumber,
    tblPriceLevels.IsRepairLevel,
    tblServiceOrders.ContractNumber AS ServiceOrderContractNumber,
    tblSysCompanySettings.HideGSTaxRelatedInformation,
    tblSysCompanySettings.ItemsServicedPrintOnInvoice,
    tblSysDisclaimerSettings.SalesInvoiceDisclaimer,
    tblSysDisclaimerSettings.MSPAgreementInvoiceDisclaimer AS ServiceInvoiceDisclaimer,
    tblSysPBSettings.PrintItemorPartNum,
    VoidedByReps.RepName AS VoidedByRepName,
    tblInvoices.TotalNetInvoice,
    InvoiceDetailPriceBook.PartNumber AS DetailPartNumber,
    InvoiceDetailPriceBook.UnitOfMeasure AS DetailUnitOfMeasure,
    InvoiceDetailPriceBook.Features AS DetailFeatures,
    tblSysDisclaimerSettings.ContractInvoiceDisclaimer,
    tblInvoices.ProviderTax,
    tblServiceOrders.BriefDescription AS SOBriefDescription,
    tblInvoices.GSTaxComputedBeforeTradeIn,
    tblInvoices.TaxComputedBeforeTradeIn,
    tblInvoices.ProviderTaxRate,
    tblInvoices.FreightTaxable,
    tblInvoices.GSTIsTaxable,
    tblInvoices.ProjectKeyID,
    InvoicesReps.RepName,
    tblAccounts.AccountNumber AS Expr1,
    tblAccounts.AccountID,
    tblInvoices.Terms,
    tblInvoices.Reference,
    tblInvoices.ARCustomerNumber,
    tblInvoices.PONumber,
    tblInvoices.ShipVia,
    tblServiceOrders.DateRequested,
    tblServiceOrders.DateOpened,
    tblServiceOrders.SONumber AS ServiceOrderSONumber,
    tblSysReportSettings.InvoiceCommentsAtEnd,
    tblInvoices.SourceDocument,
    tblTaxCodes.HasTieredDistrict,
    tblExchange.ExchangeKeyID,
    tblCustomerInventory.ItemID AS ExchangeItemID,
    tblCustomerInventory.ItemDescription AS ExchangeItemDescription,
    tblCustomerInventory.SerialNumber AS ExchangeSerialNumber,
    tblSOPartsUsed.Memo AS SOPartsNotes,
    tblInvoiceDetail.Taxable AS DetailIsTaxable,
    tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.Taxable AS AssemblyIsTaxable,
    tblInvoices.IsFinalProgressiveInvoice,
    tblInvoiceDetail.IsProgressiveInvoiceItem,
    tblInvoices.IsProgressiveInvoice,
    tblInvoices.TotalPriceCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalTaxCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalGSTaxCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalProviderTaxCredited,
    tblInvoices.TotalFreightCredited,
    tblInvoices.DiscountAllowed,
    tblInvoices.AmountPaid,
    (
        SELECT MAX(SOItemsServicedKeyID) AS Expr1
        FROM tblSOItemsServiced
        WHERE (SONumber = tblServiceOrders.SONumber)
        ) AS SOItemsServicedKeyID,
    tblInvoiceDetail.CommentOnly,
    ServiceOrderContacts.ContactName AS SOContactName,
    tblServiceOrders.ContactPhone AS SOContactPhone,
    tblServiceOrders.ContactPhoneLocation AS SOContactPhoneLocation,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) FormattedPhoneNumber
        FROM tblPhoneNumbers
        WHERE (ContactNumber = 0)
            AND (PrimaryIndicator = 1)
            AND (COALESCE(PhoneLocation, '') <> 'Fax')
            AND (AccountNumber = tblAccounts.AccountNumber)
        ) AS AccountPhone,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) PhoneLocation
        FROM tblPhoneNumbers AS tblPhoneNumbers_1
        WHERE (ContactNumber = 0)
            AND (PrimaryIndicator = 1)
            AND (COALESCE(PhoneLocation, '') <> 'Fax')
            AND (AccountNumber = tblAccounts.AccountNumber)
        ) AS AccountPhoneLocation,
    COALESCE(tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount.AmountDue, 0.00) AS AmountDue,
    COALESCE(tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount.Unappliedpayments, 0.00) AS Unappliedpayments,
    COALESCE(tblTaxCodes.IsHarmonizedTaxCode, 0) AS IsHarmonizedTaxCode,
    tblInvoices.GSTax + tblInvoices.Tax AS HSTax
FROM tblPriceBook AS InvoiceAssemblyPriceBook
RIGHT JOIN tblPriceBook AS InvoiceDetailPriceBook
RIGHT JOIN tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail
RIGHT JOIN tblCustomerInventory
FULL JOIN tblSOPartsUsed
INNER JOIN tblExchange
    ON tblSOPartsUsed.SOPartsUsedKeyID = tblExchange.FKSOPartsUsed
        ON tblCustomerInventory.CustomerInventoryKeyID = tblExchange.FKCustomerInventory RIGHT JOIN tblInvoiceDetail
        ON tblSOPartsUsed.FKInvoiceDetail = tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceDetailKeyID
            ON tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.FKInvoiceDetail = tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceDetailKeyID
                ON InvoiceDetailPriceBook.ItemID = tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID
                    ON InvoiceAssemblyPriceBook.ItemID = tblInvoiceAssemblyDetail.ItemID LEFT JOIN tblPriceLevels
                    ON tblInvoiceDetail.PriceLevel = tblPriceLevels.PriceLevelsKeyID RIGHT JOIN tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount INNER JOIN tblAccounts
                ON tvwr_TotalAmountDuePerAccount.AccountNumber = tblAccounts.AccountNumber RIGHT JOIN tblReps AS VoidedByReps RIGHT JOIN tblInvoices AS tblInvoices LEFT JOIN tblTaxCodes
        ON tblInvoices.SalesTaxCode = tblTaxCodes.SalesTaxCode LEFT JOIN tblReps AS InvoicesReps
        ON tblInvoices.SalesRep = InvoicesReps.RepNumber
            ON VoidedByReps.RepNumber = tblInvoices.StatusBy LEFT JOIN tblServiceOrders LEFT JOIN tblContacts AS ServiceOrderContacts
        ON tblServiceOrders.ContactNumber = ServiceOrderContacts.ContactNumber
            ON tblInvoices.SONumber = tblServiceOrders.SONumber
                ON tblAccounts.AccountNumber = tblInvoices.AccountNumber
                    ON tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceNumber = tblInvoices.InvoiceNumber LEFT JOIN tblContacts AS tblContacts
                    ON tblAccounts.PrimaryContactNumber = tblContacts.ContactNumber CROSS JOIN tblSysPBSettings CROSS JOIN tblSysCompanySettings CROSS JOIN tblSysReportSettings CROSS JOIN tblSysDisclaimerSettings
WHERE (tblInvoices.MSPAgreementNumber <> 0)
```

Comment: Okay, my jaw dropped at the length of this query.

Comment: See the problem... I'ts doing my head in!

Comment: Did you add the "Full Join" and "tblSOPartsUsed" into the from clause or was it already there?  If there is not matching data in the second select you can just use "NULL as SOPartsNotes" without pulling anything from tblSOPartsUsed.  Are you getting an error, or just bad results?

Comment: the tblSOPartsUsed in From was already there, but it was an Inner Join initially. I'm not getting an error it's just not giving me the data I am after.

Comment: Issue is fixed, I managed to copy each half of the view into a new view, manually tick off the tblSOPartsUsed.memo from the GUI and copied the two together which made the view work great

Answer (score 0):

I managed to copy each half of the view into a new view, manually tick off the tblSOPartsUsed.memo from the GUI and copied the two together which made the view work great